# create token using laravel 5.5 tymon jwt for mobile app (for none-authenticated users)

Tags: laravel-5, jwt

as indicated in the title I want to make sure that the users who consume the API whether in the mobile app or the web browser are those who are using my website or my mobile app no third party can use my API

this is can be done easily by creating a token for the users who can login with the right credentials but my project consists of parts where authenticated users or none-authenticated users can do CRUD

so basically I want only the users who use my mobile app or my website to be able to use my API no third party can use my API except for those who are granted access to use my API

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can declare `ApiController` from where you can check `user_token` and check their headers. For this, you have to create a table called `user_tokens`. The table should look like this:

```
+-----+---------+-----------+------------+
| id  | user_id | usertoken | timestamps |
+-----+---------+-----------+------------+
```

This table has `one-to-one` relation with the `users` table. From the device in which you want to use the `api` you have to pass this `user_id` and `usertoken` as `headers`. Then you have to check the headers from your `ApiController` for authentication by the code below:

```
public function checktoken(Request $request){

    if ($request->headers->has('usertoken')) {
        $token = $request->header('usertoken');
        $usertoken = UserToken::where('usertoken',$token)->first();

        if ($usertoken) {
            return $usertoken;
        }

        return false;        
    }

    return false;
}
```

Here is an example to login from the api:

```
public function postlogin(Request $request){

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), User::$auth_rules);

    if ($validator->fails()){
        $result['status']='fail';
        $result['message']='Validation unseccessful';
        return $result;
    }

    $remember=$request->has('remember')?true:false;
    $user=User::where('email',$request->get('email'))->first();

    if (Auth::attempt(array('phone' => $request->input('email'), 'password' => $request->input('password')), $remember)){
        $usertoken=new UserToken;
        $usertoken->user_id=$user->id;
        $usertoken->usertoken=$user->remember_token;
        $save=$usertoken->save();

        if ($save){
            $usertoken=UserToken::where('user_id', $user->id)->first();
            $token=$usertoken->usertoken;
            if (!$token) {
                $token=str_random(60);
                $usertoken->usertoken=$token;
                $update=$usertoken->update();
            }               
            $result['status']='success';
            $result['message']='Login successful';
            $result['data']=$token;
            return $result;
        }                   
    }

    $result['status']='fail';
    $result['message']='Invalid credentials';
    return $result;

}
```

Now you can check the token as authentication from server side by this (soupose your user wants to change password):

```
public function postchangepassword(Request $request){

    $usertoken = $this->checktoken($request); // this here gets the token for authentication

    if ($usertoken) {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), User::$password_rules);
        if ($validator->fails()){
            $result['status']='fail';
            $result['message']='Validation unseccessful';
            return $result;
        }

        $user=$usertoken->user()->first(); // you are geting authenticated user by this

        if(Hash::check($request->get('password'), $user->password)){    

            $user->password=bcrypt($request->get('newpassword'));
            $update=$user->update();

            if($update){
                $result['status']='successful';
                $result['message']='Password updated';
                return $result; 
            }

            $result['status']='fail';
            $result['message']='Password could not be updated';
            return $result;
        }

        $result['status']='fail';
        $result['message']='Current password is wrong';
        return $result;
    }

    $result['status']='fail';
    $result['message']='Invalid token';
    return $result;
}
```

Hope this helps.